# Parsers for User Agent Strings?

Tags: python, regex, http, parsing, user-agent

I am trying to parse User Agent strings and ideally extract them into a Python dictionary. After scouring the net, it seems that the only way to do this is by programming a regex parser from scratch. As far as I know, the best solution available so far is what the contributors at https://github.com/ua-parser have done.

Now, consider the following User Agent (UA) string:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko`

When I feed it through the above mentioned ua-parser (in Python), I get the following dictionary:

```
{   'device': {'brand': None, 'family': 'Other', 'model': None},
    'os': {   'family': 'Windows 7',
              'major': None,
              'minor': None,
              'patch': None,
              'patch_minor': None},
    'string': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'user_agent': {'family': 'IE', 'major': '11', 'minor': '0', 'patch': None}}
```

**So here is my question**: Why does the returned `user_agent` field say that its family is IE 11, when clearly, there is no reference to IE in the original UA string? And what happened to the first keyword, namely Mozilla/5.0? Why is Windows NT 6.1 considered as a family of Windows 7? It seems to me that the output dictionary has little to do with the input UA string. Try feeding the UA string in the following online parser and see for yourself:

https://udger.com/resources/online-parser?Fuas=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+Trident%2F7.0%3B+rv%3A11.0%29+like+Gecko%0D%0A&Fip=&test=&action=analyze

Am I crazy or are these parsers completely off the mark?

*Side note*: User Agent strings follow a well-defined format as specified by the HTTP standards https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3. You'd therefore think that parsing them is a straightforward matter but it seems not to be the case...

Comment: `Trident` is `IE` engine. `Windows 7` always sends `Windows NT 6.1`. Ask Bill Gates why he decides to use name `Windows NT 6.1` in his code.

Comment: BTW: `Windows 8` uses `Windows NT 6.2`, `Windows 8.1` uses `Windows NT 6.3`, `Windows 2000` uses `Windows NT 5.0` and `Window NT` uses `Windows NT 4.0` :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the interpretation of browser identification string is not a programming issue. Also the question seems to complain about functionality of an external library as the main problem. This should be discusses on the project website not on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break up each parameter and understand it:

**Mozilla/5.0** - Is the general token that says the browser is Mozilla compatible, and is common to almost every browser today.

**Windows NT 6.1** - Platform of the browser. Windows NT is a the kernel Windows operating systems are based off. Each version is a different version of Windows (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions)).

**Trident/7.0** - Is the layout engine used by IE. It is split up to *Engine_Name/Version*.

**rv:11.0** - Version of browser. Here indicating IE11.

**like Gecko** - In order for websites to identify the right CSS rules for the browser they search for a certain string in the User-Agent. By adding the `like Gecko` websites know that IE is capable of handling Gecko templated CSS rules.
You can read more about the IE User-Agent on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx).